# Has anybody ever created a Flash RIA with Java server on the side?

Tags: java, flash, remoting, ria

We are trying to create Flash online game)
Can you help me to choose the best way to communicate this two technology? Now I have chosen BlazeDS, but I am not sure, mb XML socket, or anything else.....

Answer (score 4):

IMHO BlazeDS with AMF is most common configuration.

For games you usually need speed, and minimal bandwidth, AMF gives you this, I doubt XML/SOAP could fit in this scenario unless you are using backend just for scores etc.

Comment: Thanx a lot. Mb someone create this kind of App in production scale?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [smartfox](http://www.smartfoxserver.com/). It's really the easiest and most robust solution for multiplayer games.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are talking about - Id start with the blazeds samples that come with turnkey distribution, they demo different polling types consumer/subscriber model etc.